# How does "percentage" work?

Tags: sentence-construction

1. Are the following sentences correct?

> a) What percentage of human body is water?
>
> b) What is the percentage of water in human body?

2. I found these sentences:

> c) What percentage of women return to work after having a baby?
>
> d) The percentage of live births continues to increase.

Why is "return" used in c) and not "returns"?

Why is "continues" is used in d) and not "continue"?

Comment: Your sentences lack an article before human.Think of percentage as a substitute for the word 'number' and this may help you read it.  Return agrees with percentage; continues agrees percentage.

Comment: Thank you. But "return" suggests that "percentage" is plural while "continues" suggests that it is singular. Is it singular or plural?

Comment: "What percentage of women returns" is correct as we can see from the following answer: "The percentage of women who return to work after having a baby is 78%." However, it is a very common error for a verb to get disassociated  from a singular subject if a plural noun or pronoun intervenes.